# Event listener to dynamically created buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, events, dynamic

I have a button that append a template containing few divs and buttons.
The first button "btnGenerateResult_0" works fine probably because it exists when the page loads, while "btnGenerateResult_1" gets created but doesn't work.
How and where can I fix the event listener and attach it to these buttons, I need four buttons?

The bellow code is inside a document.readey function():

```
$(`#btnGenerateResult_${active}`).click(function () 
{
    var newrow = "";
    for (var i = 1; i < TablesObj[activeTableObj[active]].length; i ++ ) 
    {
            newrow = "";
            newrow= "<tr><td>"  +  TablesObj[activeTableObj[active]][i][0] +  
                    "</td><td>"  + TablesObj[activeTableObj[active]][i][3] + 
                    "</tr>";
            $(`#resultTableMain_${active}`).append(newrow); 
    }
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add the event listener to the newly created button after you have created it:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

function handleButtonClicked(e) {
   console.log(`Button ${ e.target.textContent } clicked!`);
}

Array.from(container.children).forEach((button) => {
  button.onclick = handleButtonClicked;
});

setTimeout(() => {
  const newButton = document.createElement('BUTTON');

  newButton.textContent = 'C';

  container.appendChild(newButton);
  
  // Add the event listener to this new button as well:
  newButton.onclick = handleButtonClicked;
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button>A</button>
  <button>B</button>
</div>
```

Another option, which might scale better, is to use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation). It consists of adding a single event listener to the parent or any common ancestor for all those buttons. The click event will then bubble app and you can use `e.target` to find out which button the event originated from:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

container.onclick = (e) => {  
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') {
    console.log('Something else clicked...');
    
    return;
  }
  
  console.log(`Button ${ e.target.textContent } clicked!`);
};

setTimeout(() => {
  // See how this works with dynamically created buttons as wel, withiout adding the
  // event listener to each of them individually. However, the event might be
  // triggered from undesired elements as well (click in the space between the
  // buttons), so you need to check for that, as you can see above.

  const newButton = document.createElement('BUTTON');

  newButton.textContent = 'C';

  container.appendChild(newButton);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button>A</button>
  <button>B</button>
</div>
```